# How to open specific URLs with a custom program from Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I would like my Firefox to open specific URLs with a specific program.

Concrete: I would like my Firefox to launch VLC when I browse to a video on Youtube.

Is this configurable? Is there an extension with such feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the [Open With](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/open-with/) add-on. Now I can right-click on a Youtube Link and open it with VLC.